# Java / Eclipse profiling: Is there a way to show the number of method calls to each method?

Tags: java, eclipse, profiler

I'm currently debugging an applications which lacks performance in one certain situation, expanding a tree node in a custom tree visualizing control, and our assumption is that it is due to some recursive calculation for the tree values.

Now the idea was to trace the number of calls to each method to identify methods which are uncommonly often called, which may give us more insight where to look for the performance issue.

Is there a built in profiler in Eclipse / some other way to trace the number of method calls (without or preferable with summed up run time within each method)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VisualVM CPU profiler can help you : https://visualvm.java.net/profiler.html.

Comment: Thanks, got it up running and already could identify the problem. Yet I didn't get the Eclipse Plugin to work (the VisualVM launcher), but that's another problem which I have to look.

Comment: glad to have helped :)

Comment: VisualVM was moved to https://visualvm.github.io/index.html